# no matching function call when using lambda function as an argument of a template function

Tags: c++

I defined a class that receives an lambda function through constructor. The code is as follows. Why did the definition of `t0` pass compilation after using the `std::forward`, and `t1` incur an error?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <typename Func>
class Test {
 public:
  Test(Func &&func) : m_func(std::forward<Func &&>(func)) {}
  void Run() { m_func(); }

 private:
  Func &&m_func;
};

template <typename Func>
class Foo {
 public:
  Foo(Func &func) : m_func(func) {}
  void Run() { m_func(); }

 private:
  Func &m_func;
};

int main() {
  const auto print = []() { std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl; };
  using Print = decltype(print);

  Test<decltype(print)> t0(std::forward<Print&&>(print));
  t0.Run();

  Test<void()> t1(Print{});
  t1.Run();

  Foo<decltype(print)> t3(std::forward<Print&&>(print));
  t3.Run();

  Foo<void()> t4(Print{});
  t4.Run();
}
```

[Update]

The definition of `t1` should be as following. thx for @JaMiT.

```
Test<void(*)()> t1([]() { std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl; });
```

But I'm still confused about the definition of `t0`. If I deletes the `std::forward`, it incurs a compilation error.

[Update]

It works if I change the definition of `t0` to `Test<void (*)()> t0(print);`. What's the difference between `Test<decltype(print)> t0(print);` that causes a compilation error?

Comment: who says that it "needs" `std::forward` ? Is that what you found out by trial and error?

Comment: The use of `std::forward` imho is wrong here, since `Func &&func` is not a forwarding reference: `Func` is not a parameter of the constructor. `std::forward<decltype(print) &&>(print)` should be used by `std::move(print)` and using the source of the move after the completion of the constructor is bad practice even though it's ok here, since no modification happens via the rvalue reference. Also storing a rvalue reference is questionable at best...

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number It passes the compilation after adding `std::forward`.

Comment: im no native english speaker either, but if you write "I added `std::forward` and then it compiles" would be much better than "it needs `std::forward`". Actually "it needs `std::forward`" is a false premise, while "i tried this and that happened" is useful information

Comment: @fabian  It passes the compilation after adding std::forward for the definiation of `t0`. The definition of `t1` is the motivation of using a rvalue reference.

Comment: Are you aware that in cases t1 and t4 you have dangling reference? Even if it will compile runing this code will be UB.

Comment: Your problem mainly in incorrect template parameters, you can use `auto t = Test(...);` and then almost everything will compile. But there still will be issue with dangling refernce.

Comment: Neither the initialization `t1` nor the one of `t4` work: lambda expressions create objects, not functions and your objects are not convertible to type `void()`... What you should be doing here is to create a single template and add deduction guidlines to deduce the template parameters to `SomeType&` for lvalue references passed and `SomeType` in all other cases, see the following example: https://godbolt.org/z/ja58q7xon

Comment: @fabian Is it necessary for the `m_func` to be a reference?

Comment: Homework project for you: what happens if you change `Test<void()> t1` to `Test<void(*)()> t1`? Can you explain what the difference is? (Comment out `t4` for this experiment, since that has another issue that interferes with the result.)

Comment: @JaMiT thx. I cann't explain the difference literally. Maybe `void()` is wrong on syntax. But I know that the `void(*)()` is what I want to write actually. It likes using `typedef void(*pFunc)();` to define a function pointer pointing to functions that have no return  value and don't need any argument.

Comment: @sklott Could you help explain the dangling refernce issue?

Comment: In t1 and t4 case what you are passing to constructor is "temporary object" which is destryed at the end of t1 and t4 declaration expression. You saving reference to this object in `m_func` variable. But it references basically destroyed object. So when you call `Run()` in these cases you invoke Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @sklott What if using `m_func(std::move(func))`to init `m_func` in constructor instead?

Comment: It will be ok with either copy or move if `m_func` is declared as `Func m_func;`. Also, you probably should use `std::forward` inside template when using forwarding reference and `std::move` outside.

Answer (score 0):

> Why did the definition of `t0` pass compilation after using the `std::forward`,

Because that is how you declared the constructor of `Test`. The constructor takes as its parameter an rvalue reference to the template parameter. You explicitly provided `decltype(print)` as the template argument, so the constructor takes an rvalue of that type. There will be no copying (no pass by value), and an lvalue reference will not cut it. You must provide an rvalue.

By adding `std::forward<Print&&>`, you converted `print` to an rvalue. (It would have been simpler to add `std::move` instead. Rule of thumb: use `std::forward` when dealing with a "placeholder" type, such as a template parameter, and use `std::move` when dealing with a fixed type.)

***Caution:** After using `std::forward<Print&&>(print)` or `std::move(print)`, you should treat `print` as uninitialized. That is, your initialization of `t3` is a potential bug.*

Another tweak that would make this compile is to specify `decltype(print)&` (with the ampersand at the end) as the template argument. When `Func` is an lvalue reference, `Func&&` [collapses](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Reference_collapsing) to `Func`, which means the constructor would take an lvalue reference instead of an rvalue reference. (Reference collapsing is a key component of [forwarding references](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references), on which perhaps you based your code? However, forwarding references would require the constructor to itself be a template.)

---

> and `t1` incur an error?

For `t1`, you specified the template argument as `void()`, which is the type of a function. Lambdas are objects, not functions, so there is a type mismatch.

On the other hand, a lambda with no captures (nothing inside the `[]`) can implicitly convert to a *pointer* to a function. This is a place where confusion lurks, because functions also decay to pointers so people can get used to interchanging function types and pointer to function types. To specify a pointer to a function, use `void(*)()` instead of `void()`.

***Caution:** Implicit conversions can [wreak havoc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Dangling_references) when combined with references. Then again, you were already in the danger zone when you combined temporary objects (`Print{}`) with references. Your code would be safer if you changed the data member to `Func m_func;`. In addition to avoiding dangling references, this would be more efficient (less indirection) when storing a pointer-to-function.*

```cpp
template <typename Func>
class Test {
 public:
  // Constructor can still take a reference and forward it to the member.
  Test(Func &&func) : m_func(std::forward<Func &&>(func)) {}
  void Run() { m_func(); }

 private:
  Func m_func; // Not necessarily a reference
};
```

There are still potential issues (e.g. `Func` could be specified as a reference type), but at least this is safer. I choose to treat the remaining issues as out-of-scope for this question about syntax.

---

> It works if I change the definition of `t0` to `Test<void (*)()> t0(print);`.

This combines some concepts I presented earlier. The template argument is now a pointer to a function, so your lambda (`print`) will undergo an implicit conversion, similar to the `t1` case. The result of an implicit conversion is an rvalue, which is what your constructor expects (no need to forward or move).

***Caution:** By "works", you really mean "compiles". The fact that you asked this question suggests you already know the following, but for the benefit of others: getting code to compile is a necessary step, but that by itself does not mean the code is correct and works as intended. Don't be satisfied when a tweak you do not understand makes your code compile – ask questions!*